# Parenthesis highlighting - emacs

Tags: vim, emacs

I want to have the matching bracket\parenthesis highlighted when I have the cursor over the closing one.
I got the parenthesis highlighting using `(show-paren-mode t)` but this seems to highlight the parenthesis only when I am over the opening side; how do I fix that?

Using Gnu Emacs from the terminal.

If I can the same functionality that comes by default in `vim` that'd be really good because it does the above and avoids the latency (highlights right away, `(setq show-paren-delay 0)` seems to do nothing)

Comment: I've been very happy with using a library called `highlight-parenthesis`:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightParentheses  and here is the Github link:  https://github.com/nschum/highlight-parentheses.el

Comment: @lawlist thanks, I figured that I should simply place the cursor after the closing parenthesis; considering that, should I remove the question or post an answer? (and I'll check the library, thanks again)

Comment: I'll leave that decision in your hands -- if you feel the thread would benefit others in the future, then perhaps make a more concise question title that describes the exact issue and post an answer that answers that precise issue.  That way, others Googling it in the future can know right away whether the particular thread might answer a same or similar issue.  If you do not believe the thread will be particularly helpful to potential future internet searchers, then go ahead and remove the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show-paren-mode` does that, the difference from `vim`'s behaivor is that it'll highlight the matching opening parenthesis if the cursor is AFTER the closing parenthesis instead of highlighting it when the cursor is at closing one.

Comment: In Emacs 24.4 this mode will also highlight blocks in some modes, such as begin/end in Ruby Mode.